# How do you close the material UI context menu, without displaying the default context menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the material UI menu to display a context menu on a div, as in https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#context-menu

This works I can right-click and it displays.

However, the material-ui context menu when displayed **injects a transparent div covering the whole screen behind the menu**. This means any further clicks are intercepted by this element. It seems this element will close the menu when a left click is detected but will move and continue displaying the **same context menu** if you right-click anywhere else on the page, including where the context menu is irrelevant.

Is there any way to display the menu without this transparent div which is removing control from my page?

You can see this action in the example: https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#context-menu
Right-click on the text, then right-click anywhere else (while the menu is still displayed) and you can trigger the menu to appear all over the page, even in the app bar, where the menu options make no sense.

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm facing the same issue and found out that even if the `Menu` is appended to `document.body`, the `onContextMenu` callback is still being fire when right-clicking on the overlay.

Comment: The solution I found was to render the `Menu` outside the element with the `onContextMenu` callback, but still not great.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in like this:

```
export default function MenuPopupState() {
  return (
    <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-menu">
      {popupState => {
        const menuProps = bindMenu(popupState);
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              {...bindTrigger(popupState)}
            >
              Open Menu
            </Button>
            <Menu
              {...menuProps}
              onContextMenu={event => {
                event.preventDefault();
              }}
              onMouseDown={e => {
                menuProps.onClose();
              }}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Cake</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Death</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }}
    </PopupState>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-szpbr?file=/demo.js

Comment: How does this answers the question? OP is using `onContextMenu()` to display the menu.